# I want to add a search bar to the top of my TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I'm having a hard time adding a functioning search bar to the top of my Table View. My code without it runs fine for selecting the colleges, but I need a search table to filter through the list of universities.

I've tried to add a search bar that I find from online sources, but they end up using arrays for their list of items. My code doesn't do it in the same format for the items I show in my TableView. That would be great if there is a way to add a search bar without creating an array for the items listed in my Table view.

```
import UIKit

class MasterViewController: UITableViewController{
        
        
    var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
    var objects = [Any]()
    
    
    
    var UniName: [String] = ["The University of Texas at Austin", "Rice University", "Texas A&M University", "Baylor university", "The University of Texas at El Paso", "southern methodist university", "The University of Texas at Dallas", "Texas Tech University", "University of North Texas", "Texas A&M University-Commerce"]
    var UniAddress: [String] = ["110 Inner Campus Drive Austin, TX 78705", "6100 Main St., Houston, TX 77005-1892", "Administration Building, 400 Bizzell St, College Station, TX 77843", "1311 S 5th St, Waco, TX 76706", "500 W University Ave, El Paso, TX 79968", "6425 Boaz Lane, Dallas, TX 75205", "800 W Campbell Rd, Richardson, TX 75080", "2500 Broadway, Lubbock, TX 79409", "1155 Union Cir, Denton, TX 76203", "2200 Campbell St, Commerce, TX 75428"]
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem
        if let split = splitViewController {
            let controllers = split.viewControllers
            detailViewController = (controllers[controllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as? DetailViewController
        }
    }
    
    
    
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = splitViewController!.isCollapsed
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }
    // MARK: - Segues
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
                controller.setNewAddress(Member: UniName[indexPath.row], formap: UniAddress[indexPath.row])
                controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
                controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
            }
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Table View
    
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return UniName.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableViw.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel!.text = UniName[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Unless you *only* want a table view, you are probably best to avoid `UITableViewController` and just add a `UITableView` to a `UIViewController`. It is too hard to add other UI components to a `UITableViewController`. Don't use multiple, related arrays for your data. Create a struct with the required properties and use an array of those structs. This will not only make searching easier, it avoid a whole raft of potential problems if you want to be able to add, delete or move rows later.

Comment: @Paulw11 Adding search to a UITableViewController is trivial. Use UISearchController and set it to the table controller's navigationItem's searchController property.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite broad so first things first. You should probably first start with a model definition for your data.

```swift
// This is a model for our table
struct University {
    let name: String
    let address: String

    static let allUniversities = [
        University(name: "The University of Texas at Austin", address: "110 Inner Campus Drive Austin, TX 78705"),
        University(name: "Rice University", address: "6100 Main St., Houston, TX 77005-1892"),
        University(name: "Texas A&M University", address: "Administration Building, 400 Bizzell St, College Station, TX 77843")
        // Add more universities here
    ]
}
```

This will clearly separate the model from the controller logic.

The best way to customize tables is to not use UITablewViewController but rather use UITableView with UISearchBar inside UIViewController. If using a storyboard it would look like this:

[image: Storyboard hierarchy]

It's important to add the search bar into the UITableView on top position. Now here's what the view controller could look like.

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // Make sure you connect those IBOutlets to your Storyboard
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    // This is our main data source
    let data: [University] = University.allUniversities

    // This is where we save filtered results from search and display it
    var searchedResults: [University] = []

    // This is a flag that determines if to show all the results or only the searched results
    var isSearching = false {
        didSet {
            tableView.reloadData() // Reload the data if the flag changes
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        tableView.dataSource = self
        searchBar.delegate = self
    }

    // MARK: - Helper methods

    /// Retuns active dataset based on the search state
    func activeDataset() -> [University] {
        if isSearching {
            return searchedResults
        } else {
            return data
        }
    }

    /// Returns a list of univerties matching given query
    func filteredUniversities(query: String) -> [University] {
        return data.filter { $0.name.contains(query) }
    }
}
```

As you can see in the `viewDidLoad` method, we added the `ViewController` as dataSource for the table and delegate for the search bar so we need to make sure to conform to those protocols

```swift
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        let universities = activeDataset()
        let university = universities[indexPath.row] // Get data for the row

        cell.textLabel!.text = university.name // Update the cell with the data

        return cell
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1 // Our data are all in 1 section
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return activeDataset().count
    }
}
```

Here we created a logic to show either search results or all the data depending on if the search is active.

```swift
extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        // Check if the searched text has at least 1 character otherwise show all results
        guard searchText != "" else {
            isSearching = false
            searchedResults.removeAll()
            return
        }

        searchedResults = filteredUniversities(query: searchText)
        isSearching = true
    }
}
```

And we use the `UISearchBarDelegate` to determine when the user types something into the search bar.

See full code [here](https://gist.github.com/kafejo/be06b47545aa3cb3a3dff397122370c8).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you want https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/2897305-searchcontroller
When you've got your UITableView working I'd also recommend switching to UICollectionView lists see here. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/implementing_modern_collection_views

FWIW UICollectionViewController is usually fine, the automatic deselection of cells in coordination with UINavigationController is mostly broken, so just do it yourself, it's easy enough to do.